# Calling a parameterized constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor

Very basic question, new to programming, but I don't get how to call the parameterized constructor in Java.

I have the following constructor in my `Card` class:

```
public Card(int n) {
    face = Face.values()[n%13];
    suit = Suit.values()[n%4];
}
```

I'm trying to utilize it in my Deck class:

```
public class Deck {
    private Card[] deck;
    private int nextCard;

    public Deck(){
        nextCard = 0;
        Card crd = new Card();      
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            deck[i] = crd.Card(i);
            nextCard++;                 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to assign every member of the deck array a card from the `Card` constructor. This obviously didn't work, and if someone could tell me the why and what to do instead, that would be really appreciated.

> You can call the toString like this --> `crd.toString();` or the setter like `card.setCard(i);`

I'm not following how to use the parameterized constructor that shares the class name. Help?

---

#### Edit

I should add my professor's instruction for this portion:

> The `Deck`'s default constructor should fill an array of 52 unique `Card` objects.  Use a loop and pass the loop's counter to the `Card` constructor as its argument.

Answer (score 3):

```
private Card[] deck;

public Deck() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        deck[i] = new Card(i);      
    }
}
```

When you create a 'new' instance of Card, the constructor is executed. Your constructor takes an int argument, so all you need to do is to call

```
Card c = new Card(i);
```

...where 'i' is a number. In your case, you just put the object straight into the array without holding a reference to it

```
deck[i] = new Card(i);
```

I also removed some redundant lines of code too, which might clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new Card object in your for loop, not try and reuse the same one and just re-construct it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    deck[i] = new Card(i);
    nextCard++;                 
}
```

Please read up on the documentation on Oracles site if you are still confused about Constructors:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: That's actually what I initially did, but it won't compile. It says there is an error that this line deck[i] = new Card(i);  and it says that crd is not being utilized.  
Oh, I get what you are saying. I think that did the trick, thanks :)

Comment: If you mean it says the variable is unused, then its a warning, not an error. You code should compile fine as is. If you post the exact error that shows when you compile, I can try to help more.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at cards.Deck.<init>(Deck.java:45)
 at cards.DeckDriver.main(DeckDriver.java:38)
line 38
public static void main (String [ ] args)
 {
  
  Deck aDeck = new Deck();
  
  System.out.println (aDeck.toString());
 

 }
line 45:
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
   deck[i] = new Card(i);

Comment: You never initialized Deck. Should be Card [] deck = new Card [53]

Comment: Thank you! This has helped greatly. My toString method now prints 52 different cards.